# How to move and replace files from FTP folder to another folder in same FTP

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to move some XML files in an FTP location to another location in the same FTP. I tried with the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
def ftpPush(filepathSource, filename, filepathDestination):
    try:
        ftp = FTP(ip, username, password)
        ftp.cwd(filepathDestination)
    
        ftp.storlines("STOR "+filename, open(filepathSource, 'r')) 
        ftp.quit()
        
        for fileName in os.listdir(path):
            if fileName.endswith(".xml"):
                ftpPush(filepathSource, filename, filepathDestination)
        
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
        
    finally:
        ftp.close()
```

Answer (score 12):

To move a file use the [`FTP.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.rename).

Assuming that the `filepathSource` and the `filepathDestination` are both remote files, you do:

```
ftp.rename(filepathSource, filepathDestination)
```