# Python FTP ftplib move an entire folder to another directory fails with "Cannot link to a file on another device"

Tags: python, unix, ftp, ftplib

I've come across various answers on how to move *files* from one location to another using Python ftplib (such as [How to move and replace files from FTP folder to another folder in same FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047179/how-to-move-and-replace-files-from-ftp-folder-to-another-folder-in-same-ftp)).  I'm trying to move an entire folder, including all subfolders and files, to another location.

Say I have a folder, `/FromPath/MoveThisFolder`, and this folder can have an unknown number of subfolders and files, ie `/FromPath/MoveThisFolder/A` and `/FromPath/MoveThisFolder/B`, both of which contain files, etc.

I want to move `MoveThisFolder` to `/ToPath`, such that I get `/ToPath/MoveThisFolder` with all contained subfolders and files moved over and no longer existing in `/FromPath/MoveThisFolder`.

How might I accomplish this?

From what I can tell, `ftp.rename` is meant for files, per the Python documentation:

> FTP.rename(fromname, toname)
>
> Rename file fromname on the server to toname.

If I try using ftp.rename(), I get an error that I can't resolve:

```
ftp.rename(ftp_from_loc, ftp_to_loc)
error_perm: 550 rename: Cannot link to a file on another device.
```

I also tried using `mv` within `ftp.sendcmd()` based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6393/how-do-you-move-all-files-including-hidden-from-one-directory-to-another), but I get an error

```
ftp.sendcmd('mv ' + ftp_from_loc + ' ' + ftp_to_loc)
```

> error_perm: 500 'MV /sourcePath/* /destinationPath/': command not understood.

(Of course I've replaced the actual paths with dummy names, but I've triple checked the paths and they're correct).

Answer (score 0):

There is not difference between moving/renaming a file or a folder on most systems. So `FTP.rename` can be used for directories as well.

What is generally not supported (in general, not in FTP only) is moving a file (or a directory) to another file system (let alone another drive/device). And it seems that this is exactly what you are attempting. Moving to another file system is not really *moving*, it would have to involve *copying* all files and deleting originals. While a real *moving* does not copy any data, it just moves the metadata.